# Isotope combining filters to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I have this JQuery function where I am combining all the filters

```
  var container = $('.isotope-XXX').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.list-XXX',
    layout: 'fitRows',
    filter: function() {
    ....
        return result;
    }
```

Now, there is another function on below

```
selects.change( function() {
     ...
     container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
}
```

I tried to move the value of selects to above function or vice-versa. But no use.

like this on:

```
    // Combine filters or set the value to * if buttonFilters
    inputFilter = concatValues( filterValue ) || '*';

    // Log out current filter to check that it's working when clicked
    console.log( inputFilter );

    // Trigger isotope again to refresh layout
    container.isotope();
```

But this works only on html page, not on wordpress page.

I am not sure how to combine both..!! Help anyone..

Comment: Include all your code that you are using, not `....`

Comment: Please take a look at this codepen: https://codepen.io/Knight143/pen/MozwxJ